# MockRestServiceServer Returning Null ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have the following mocked server:

`mockInteractiveServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(oauthClientConfig.getRestTemplate());`

I use this mocked server in a JUnit test case:

```
    @Test
    public void myTestMethod() throws Exception{
        
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Location", "samplePrefix/sampleTicketId");

        mockInteractiveServer
            .expect(ExpectedCount.once(), requestTo(new URI("mockURI")))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andExpect(content().string("validation content"))
            .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .headers(responseHeaders));
       
        //calls the actual service, which should call the mocked server
        String ticketId = interactiveTicketService.myMethod(new createTicketRequest());

        assertThat(ticketId).isEqualTo("sampleTicketId");

    }
```

The actual service, `InteractiveTicketService`, calls the server here:

```
public String myMethod(CreateTicketRequest createTicketRequest){

    //This builds the model object
    TicketRequest request = myBuilder.buildTicketRequest();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    //createTicketResponse is null
    ResponseEntity<String> createTicketResponse = iDOCClient.getRestTemplate()
            .postForEntity(iDOCClient.getRequestUrl() + "/interactive-documents", request, String.class);
}
```

And this is the model class I am passing to the `postForEntity()` method:

```
public class MyTicket implements TicketRequest {

  private List<Document> documents;
  private PublishingRequestWrapper data;
  private String assignedTo;
  private String requestType;
  private String templateGroup;
  private List<Object> templates;
  
  //constructors, getters & setters
 }
```

Again, the issue I am facing is that the `ResponseEntity` is always null.

Comment: Is it a Junit test with just mockito or an integration test? Can you post whole unit test class with mocks and annotations you have?

Comment: @VaibS this is just a JUnit test with mockito, there is no integration going on

Comment: In that, I doubt a Spring component (MockRestServiceServer) is required and will work. You can just mock with when().then() and that should work